# Default invalid select option in Angular 2 model-driven forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

Is there any way to achieve an invalid default select option in an Angular 2 model driven form?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<select name="DateExpiryMonth" [(ngModel)]="model.DateExpiryMonth" ngControl="dateExpiryMonth" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Month...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let month of months" [value]="month">{{ month }}</option>
</select>
```

Ideally, the `required` attribute on the select would ensure that the first `<option>` would be considered invalid by Angular 2, yet I can't find any documentation that suggests this is possible.

As it stands, the first "Month..." option is considered valid by Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an ideal solution, but I found that if I set the field in my model to either null or undefined (in your case `model.dateExpiryMonth`) that angular would consider the form invalid.